# XAMPP why is my else bug?

Tags: php, html, xampp

Evertime i load the page i get

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZeroWebsite\uploadtest.php on line 19

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="uploadtest.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<?php
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("dataimage") or die (mysql_error());

        $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

        if (!isset($file))
            echo "select an image";
        else // this is my line 19
        {
            $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
            $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

            if ($image_size==FALSE)
               echo "not a image.";
            else
            {
            if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO myimage VALUES ('','@image_name','$image')"))
                echo "problem uploading image.";
                else    
                {
                    $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
                    echo "image uploaded.<p /> Your image:<p />img src=uploadtest2.php?id=lastid>";
                    }
                }
            }?>
</body>
</html>
```

i fund this guide on youtube i just wanna make it work plzz show me what to do

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

must be

```
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: thanks you for the help but my image is not showing up on my screen do you know why ?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

To

```
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

One additional ")" is their.

Comment: thanks you for the help but my image is not showing up on my screen do you know why ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue `$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);`. Remove last `)` and it works.